# ConTeXt two columns two margins

Tags: margins, context, columns

I have two columns and I want to have some pictures in margin. I want in left column pictures in left margin and in right column pictures in right margin. It this possible in ConTeXt? This is minimal example: There is much more text and all margin texts are present in left side of all columns.

```
%interface=en translate-file=utf-8 
\starttext 
    \startcolumns[n=2] 
    Praesent ut nibh leo, eget commodo enim. \inmargin{2asdf} Aenean ac risus in lacus ultrices porttitor. 

    Praesent ut nibh leo, eget commodo enim. \inmargin{2asdf} Aenean ac risus in lacus ultrices porttitor. 
    \stopcolumns 
\stoptext
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please show some attempt you've made in achieving this and specify what you're struggling with, preferably in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Generally, I certainly think this should be possible.

Comment: At present, this is not possible. There was a [thread](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20100404.095540.d482b33b.en.html) on the context mailing list about this. Perhaps you can ask again on the context mailing list.

Comment: @Aditya Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

*(Originally posted as a comment by Aditya)*

At present, this is not possible. There was a [thread](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20100404.095540.d482b33b.en.html) on the context mailing list about this. Perhaps you can ask again on the context mailing list.